# How to automatically convert a numeric column to categorical data using statistical techniques

Tags: r, statistics, numeric, categorical-data

```
    >data
    ACC_ID     REG   PRBLT  OPP_TYPE_DESC   PARENT_ID   ACCT_NM   INDUSTRY_ID     BUY PWR     REV    QTY
    11316456    No      90              A   2122628569      INF          7379    10190.82    6500    1
    11456476   Yes       1              I   2385888136   Module          9199    17441.72    466.5   31
    13453245    No      10              D   2122628087   Wooden          3559    44279.21    2500    500
    15674568    No       1              I   2702074521     Nine          7379    183218.8    25.91   1
```

Above is the given dataset

When I load the same in R, I have the following structure

```
    >str(data)
    $ ACC_ID         : int  11316974 11620677 11865091  ...
    $ REG         : Factor w/ 2 levels "No  ","Yes ": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
    $ PRBLT          : int  90 1 10 1 30 30 10 1 60 1 ...
    $ OPP_TYPE_DESC  : Factor w/ 3 levels "D",..: 3 2 1 2 1 1 1 3 3 2 ...
    $ PARENT_ID      : num  2.12e+09 2.39e+09 2.12e+09 2.70e+09 2.12e+09 ...
    $ ACCT_NM         : Factor w/ 20 levels "Marketing Vertical",..: 10 15 20 17 8 16 2 14 7 11 ...
    $ INDUSTRY_ID     : int  7379 9199 3559 7379 2711 7374 7371 8742 4813 2111 ..
    $ BUY PWR         : num  1014791 17442 ...
    $ REV             : num  6500 46617 250000 25564 20000 ...
    $ QTY             : int  1 31 500 1 6 100 ...
```

But, I would want to somehow automatically want R to output the below fields as factors instead of int (with the help of statistical modelling or any other technique). Ideally, these are not continuous fields but categorical nominal fields

```
    ACC_ID
    PARENT_ID
    INDUSTRY_ID
```

Whereas the REV and QTY columns should be left as is.

Also, the analysis should not be specific to the data and the columns shown here. The logic must be applicable to any data-set (with different columns) that we load in R

Can there be any method through which this is possible? Any ideas are welcome.

Thank you

Comment: I am confused with your question because you say you want to convert "with the help of statistical modelling", but then I get the feeling that you just want to make `data$ACC_ID <- as.factor(data$ACC_ID)`. What is your desired output?

Comment: What I would want is not a straight forward conversion like you just mentioned. This needs to happen at the back-end and not from our side.
For example, looking at the scatter plot of ACC_ID, we might find that everything is concentrated in a specified range. So, the algorithm should assume that this is not a numeric but a categorical variable
Another example being, length(unique(data$PRBLT))/length(data$PRBLT) - if this measure gives 5% (unique values), we could assume the data to be discrete rather than continious

Comment: @zelite what I eventually want is `data$ACC_ID <- as.factor(data$ACC_ID)` as you mentioned, but instead of the user looking into the scatter plot and other properties of the column, the algorithm in itself should analyse and direct the command of as.factor

Comment: Your question of "How can I tell if a column is categorical" seems to broad to me, or better suited to Cross Validated - it very often depends on the context of your data. A general rule could be something like `length(unique(col)) < k * length(col)`, where `k` is a tuning variable. This sets a certain tolerance ratio for number of unique values vs total values. However, this would miss things like unique IDs that are categorical but well distributed

Comment: @Chris This is what I exactly want. But I don't seem to find any statistical model/method which would help me differentiate a categorical and a continuous variable when the column in question is numeric

This is exactly done in the back end of IBM Watson when you feed in your raw data. It automatically identifies variables like ACCT_ID as categorical whereas Revenue and Quantity columns as continuous

There should be a way to classify

Comment: @AbhishekSamrat I agree - I just think that question is better suited to Cross Validated